# Empty Space in UItableView when scrolling , Using Custom Cells

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I am using multiple custom cells. Cells are on Storyboard so I am not loading any Nibs.
There is a empty space when I scroll down and load more data.

Adding reload table in willdisplaycell sort of fixes the issue , but i am looking for a proper way on doing it

[image: ScreenShot]

```
    // Tableview Protocols
#pragma mark - Table View



- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
   // NSLog(@"# of sections");
    return 1;    //count of section
}


- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    NSLog(@"Number of rows for section %li", (long)section);
    if (self.feedArticles.count < 1){
        return 0;
    } else {
        return self.feedArticles.count + 1;

    }
}


- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    if (indexPath.row == [self.feedArticles count]-1 && self.loadMore == YES) {
        [self loadUserFeed:self.currentPage];

    }

}


- (void)scrollViewDidEndDragging:(UIScrollView *)scrollView willDecelerate:(BOOL)decelerate {

}

- (void)scrollViewWillBeginDecelerating:(UIScrollView *)scrollView {

    [scrollView.delegate scrollViewDidEndDragging:scrollView willDecelerate:NO];
}



- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath;
{
    if (indexPath.row == self.feedArticles.count && indexPath.row != 0) {

        if (self.loadMore == YES){
        UITableViewCell *cell = nil;
        cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"LoadingCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
        UIActivityIndicatorView *activityIndicator = (UIActivityIndicatorView *)[cell.contentView viewWithTag:100];
        [activityIndicator startAnimating];
        return cell;
        }
        else{
            UITableViewCell *cell = nil;
            cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"noLoadingCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
            return cell;
        }


    }
     if (indexPath.row != self.feedArticles.count && self.postDataArr.count > 0) {
   // static NSString *cellIdentifier = @"FeedCell";
   // feedPostCellTableViewCell * cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];

        //feedsUICell *cell = nil;
        feedsUICell *cell = [[feedsUICell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:@"feedsUICell"];
        cell =  [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"feedsUICell"];

    if (!cell) {
        cell = [[feedsUICell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:@"feedsUICell"];
    }

         NSDictionary *ogData = [self.postDataArr objectAtIndex:indexPath.row].OGDataModel ;
         OpenGraphData *dataOG = [[OpenGraphData alloc] initWithDictionary:ogData error:nil];
         NSLog(@"%@",ogData[@"ogUrl"] );

         NSLog(@"%@",dataOG.ogUrl);

         cell.postOGData = dataOG;
         cell.postData = [self.postDataArr objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];


    cell.articleTitle.text = [self.postDataArr objectAtIndex:indexPath.row].title;
   // cell.articleContent.attributedText = [[self.postDataArr objectAtIndex:indexPath.row].content attributedString];

        cell.articleContent.text = [self.postDataArr objectAtIndex:indexPath.row].content;


        NSMutableAttributedString *truncationString = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:@"... (read more)" attributes:nil];
        [truncationString setAttributes:@{NSFontAttributeName:cell.articleContent.font} range:NSMakeRange(0, 4)];
        [truncationString addAttribute:NSForegroundColorAttributeName
                                 value:[UIColor blueColor]
                                 range:NSMakeRange(5, 9)];
        cell.articleContent.attributedTruncationToken = truncationString;



        NSAttributedString * nsattString = [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithData:[[self.postDataArr objectAtIndex:indexPath.row].content dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]
                                                                            options:@{NSDocumentTypeDocumentAttribute: NSHTMLTextDocumentType,
                                                                                      NSCharacterEncodingDocumentAttribute: @(NSUTF8StringEncoding)}
                                                                 documentAttributes:nil error:nil];
        [cell.articleContent setAttributedText:nsattString];




       // [cell.articleContent setTruncationTokenString:@"... Read More"];

//        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
//            cell.articleContent = [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithData:[[self.postDataArr objectAtIndex:indexPath.row].content dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]
//                                                                                  options:@{NSDocumentTypeDocumentAttribute: NSHTMLTextDocumentType,
//                                                                                            NSCharacterEncodingDocumentAttribute: @(NSUTF8StringEncoding)}
//                                                                       documentAttributes:nil error:nil];
//            
//        });


        //SetPhysican ID to avatar tag
        NSString *usersName = [Helper getPhysicanNameWithId:[self.postDataArr objectAtIndex:indexPath.row].user];
        cell.userName.text = usersName;
        Physician * doctorWho;
        NSNumberFormatter *f = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
        f.numberStyle = NSNumberFormatterDecimalStyle;
        NSNumber *doctorWhoID = [f numberFromString:[self.postDataArr objectAtIndex:indexPath.row].user];
        doctorWho = [Helper getModelWithName:@"Physician" andId:doctorWhoID];

        cell.presenseImage.image = [Helper getPresenceImageForPhysician:doctorWho];
        //downlaod avatar
        NSString *path=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@?physician_id=%@&image=%@",[NHPrefs getValue:@"API_BASE_URL"],API_USER_GET_SELFIE_FULL,doctorWhoID,doctorWho.image];


        SDWebImageDownloader *manager = [SDWebImageManager sharedManager].imageDownloader;
        [manager setValue:[Keychain getStringForKey:@"accessCode"] forHTTPHeaderField:@"X-ACCESSCODE"];
        [manager setValue:[[UIDevice currentDevice] UDIDWithSalt:@"punite_navio"] forHTTPHeaderField:@"X-UDID"];
        [manager setValue:[[UIDevice currentDevice] identifierForVendor].UUIDString forHTTPHeaderField:@"X-UDID7"];

        cell.userAvatar.tag  = doctorWhoID.intValue;



        [cell.userAvatar
         sd_setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:path]
         placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"person_white"]
         completed:^(UIImage *image, NSError *error, SDImageCacheType cacheType, NSURL *imageURL) {
             //NSLog(@"path %@  done",path);
         }
         ];




        cell.postDate.text = [self formatDate:[self.postDataArr objectAtIndex:indexPath.row].createdDate];
//        cell.viewsLbl.titleLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ Views",[Helper stringSanitizer:[self.postDataArr objectAtIndex:indexPath.row].views ]];
//        cell.commentsLbl.titleLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ Comments", [Helper stringSanitizer:[self.postDataArr objectAtIndex:indexPath.row].cmtCnt]];
//        cell.likesLbl.titleLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ Likes",[Helper stringSanitizer:[self.postDataArr objectAtIndex:indexPath.row].upVotes]];
         NSString *trimmedString = [[self.postDataArr objectAtIndex:indexPath.row].views stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" " withString:@""];

         int Viewsvalue = [trimmedString intValue];

         NSString *trimCount = [self.postDataArr objectAtIndex:indexPath.row].cmtCnt;
         int trimcCount = [trimCount intValue];

         NSString *trimvCount = [self.postDataArr objectAtIndex:indexPath.row].upVotes;
         int trimlikeCount = [trimvCount intValue];

       dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
             if(Viewsvalue == 0){
                 [cell.viewsLbl setTitle:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d View", Viewsvalue] forState: UIControlStateNormal];
             } else {
                  [cell.viewsLbl setTitle:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d Views", Viewsvalue] forState: UIControlStateNormal];
             }

             if([[self.postDataArr objectAtIndex:indexPath.row].cmtCnt isEqual: @"0"]){
                  [cell.commentsLbl setTitle:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d Comment", trimcCount ] forState: UIControlStateNormal];

             } else {
                   [cell.commentsLbl setTitle:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d Comments", trimcCount ] forState: UIControlStateNormal];
             }

             if([[self.postDataArr objectAtIndex:indexPath.row].upVotes isEqual: @"0"]){
                 [cell.likesLbl setTitle:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d Like", trimlikeCount] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

             } else {
          [cell.likesLbl setTitle:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d Likes", trimlikeCount] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
             }
      });



        //[[self.postDataArr objectAtIndex:indexPath.row].OGDataModel];


        if (dataOG.imageUrl == nil || dataOG.imageUrl == NULL || [dataOG.imageUrl  isEqual: @""]){
            cell.tag = 404;
        cell.OGHeight.constant = 0;
         //   [cell.openGraphImage removeFromSuperview];
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

            });
        }
        else{
            cell.OGHeight.constant = 140;
            [cell.openGraphImage sd_setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:dataOG.imageUrl]
                                     placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@""]
                                            completed:^(UIImage *image, NSError *error, SDImageCacheType cacheType, NSURL *imageURL) {

                                            }
             ];


        }

        NSString *checkVote = [self.postDataArr objectAtIndex:indexPath.row].allowVoting;
        if ([checkVote  isEqual: @"true"] || [checkVote  isEqual: @"1" ]){
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                cell.likesLbl.hidden = false;
                cell.likesButton.hidden = false;

            });


        }else {
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                cell.likesLbl.hidden = true;
                cell.likesButton.hidden = true;

            });
        }

    return cell;
    }

}



- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

    if (indexPath.row == self.feedArticles.count){
        return 40;
    } else {
        return UITableViewAutomaticDimension;
    }


    return UITableViewAutomaticDimension;
}
```